# Error using fastify-multer to upload images

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, multer, fastify

I am trying to use the fastify-multer plugin to upload files to the server and I am able to successfully get the images uploaded to the folder.
The problem is my app crashes. 
I used the fastify-cli generated structure and I am running it as a standalone server as mentioned in the README.md [here](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli#migrating-out-of-fastify-cli-start).

I am writing it as a fastify plugin.

```
"use strict";

const fp = require("fastify-plugin");

module.exports = fp(function(fastify, opts, next) {
  fastify.decorate("uploadImage", function(request) {
    const path = require("path");
    const multer = require("fastify-multer");

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: path.join(path.join(__dirname + "/uploads/")),
      filename: function(request, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
      }
    });

    var upload = multer({ storage }).single("myImage");
    upload(request, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Saved...");
        return { saved: true };
      }
    });
  });
  next();
});
```

And here is the error I get :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi looked into your issue. You are using fastify-multer in the wrong way.
Invoking `multer({ storage }).single("myImage")` you are creating a fastify's preHandler hook that accepts 3 specific parameters. You can find more on the [offical documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Hooks/). A simple working example could be the one you can see at [fastify-multer](https://github.com/fox1t/multer):

```
const server = fastify()
// register fastify content parser
server.register(multer.contentParser)

server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/profile',
  preHandler: upload.single('avatar'),
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    // request.file is the `avatar` file
    // request.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
    reply.code(200).send('SUCCESS')
  }
})
```

If you need more help just provide me a repro repo on github and I'll try to figure out what is the best solution for your case.

Let me know! :)

Comment: The app I am developing needs to upload a lot of images in different routes. I want to use it as a fastify plugin so that I can just reuse it everywhere. How do I achieve that ?

Comment: It is already ready to do that. This plugin exposes a preHandler that you can use in every route you want. You just need to pass it as preHandler hook on that specific route. You don't need to add another plugin.

Comment: Hey that worked absolutely fine! I want to run auth check in preHandler and then only upload the files. Could you suggest a way of doing it ?

Comment: Of course. `preHandler` could also be an array of handlers: preHandler: [authenticationPreHandler, upload.single('avatar')]. I suggest you [fastify-auth](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-auth)

Comment: In nginx unit your example get 
/fastify-multer/lib/lib/make-prehandler.js:174
        request.req.pipe(busboy);
                    ^
TypeError: request.req.pipe is not a function.

What can be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "In nginx unit" and can you add a repro repository?

Comment: @Maksim https://github.com/nginx/unit/issues/317 it was an issue. Pipes does not supporting now in nginx unit :-(